# UxSms service (dwm.exe) using 100% of my CPU after about a minute of idleness

Tags: windows-7, cpu

Since 2-3 days ago, I've had a problem. Whenever I watch a YouTube video or just don't do anything at all, after one-two minutes my CPU load goes crazy. I used Task Manager to find out that dwm.exe is causing the problem. Restarting its service or my entire PC hasn't helped. It stops when I move my mouse.

Does anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: From first glance this seems like a silent BTC miner. Have you checked for viruses?

Comment: As @chipperyman573 suggests, Scan for viruses.  Also update your video driver to the latest version offered by your video adapter manufacturer.

Comment: install the WPT, open a cmd.exe and run this xperf command: http://pastebin.com/pgE11HRD leave the PC idle and when you have the CPU usage issue, capture 30-45s of the high CPU usage.

Comment: I solved the problem by running multiple virus scanners. I read on the internet it was indeed a BTC miner, it's gone now. Thanks :)