# svchost relativley high usage after some time

Tags: windows-7, cpu, process, svchost, high-cpu-usage

I have Windows 7 Ultimate. sometimes (not always), after about 3-4 minutes that I don't use the computer, I hear the sound of the cpu fan (CPU: 4790K -not overclocked , fan: Deepcool 120mm liquid cooling) and then I check the task manager and I see one of svchost processes is using about 15% of cpu but after a few seconds, it gets into 0%. The services related to this process are:

> wlansvc
>
> UxSms
>
> TrkwKs
>
> SysMain
>
> PcaSvc
>
> Netman
>
> hidserv
>
> Cscservice
>
> AudioEndpointBuilder

The process priority is set to "Normal" by default. (Is this OK?) Also the process use about 295000 KB of my 16GB memory.

Sometimes there is another svchost process which disappears immediately after I click on it. I have scanned the computer by ESET Internet Security and it found no malware nor miner.Also I am not mining any cryptocurrency. I also don't have torrent downloading apps like utorrent or bittorrent.

Usually the chrome is running in my computer but I am sure that the sites I go don't have any miner and the chrome don't have unusual usage when I don't use it.

I want to know is this normal? The CPU temperature doesn't go high but I am curious why this process sometimes use this percentage of CPU. Is it ok for this process to have Normal priority or should it have below normal or low priority?

Comment: Most services will run at normal, unless they have been set to run at a background level. SVCHOST is problematic, though, because it is used by a good many other services which are not identified beyond being tagged as SVCHOST (which can also make identifying *any* process using SVCHOST problematic, never mind any rogue service). Personally, as a Windows 7 user, it does not sound like you should be worried, but have you also tried running **sfc /scannow** at the command line to check for operating system files that may have been corrupted or altered?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [svchost eating up memory](//superuser.com/q/77658)

Comment: Also...https://superuser.com/questions/396079/svchost-using-100-cpu-in-windows-7?rq=1

Comment: @YTreehuggerCymru I scanned it and it found no problem. So it seems it is OK, isn't it?

Comment: UxSkms: Desktop Window Manager Session Manager, - should not be anything to worry about.

Comment: Those processes all appear to be normal Windows services to me; but, yes, you should investigate further. I would start with the links and advice that DP and Moab have provided, plus this: https://superuser.com/questions/689749/uxsms-service-dwm-exe-using-100-of-my-cpu-after-about-a-minute-of-idleness and (linked to same post) https://pastebin.com/pgE11HRD.